# Cannot launch the Jupyter Notebook after installing Anaconda (problems with localhost)

Tags: localhost, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

After getting everything running with Anaconda, I'm able to run the Jupyter Notebook with [this question](//stackoverflow.com/q/51617979) that I asked previously.

However, I just ran CCleaner to clean my laptop because I hadn't do so for a while. Evidently, it removed the cache from Firefox. Now, whenever I run `jupyter-notebook` inside the prompt (as admin), it displays the message `The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port`.

I tried searching online for a fix but nothing worked.

This is my `netstat` output:

```
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51493        license:51494          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51494        license:51493          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51496        license:51497          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51497        license:51496          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51500        license:51501          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51501        license:51500          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51542        license:51543          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51543        license:51542          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51558        license:51559          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51559        license:51558          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51588        license:51589          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51589        license:51588          ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51982        license:65000          SYN_SENT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51983        license:65000          SYN_SENT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51984        license:65000          SYN_SENT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51985        license:65000          SYN_SENT
  TCP    192.168.1.153:49940    52.230.80.159:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.153:51502    ec2-34-214-201-8:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.153:51609    ti-in-f189:https       ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.153:51880    104.17.110.77:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.153:51884    151.101.129.69:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.153:51955    hkg12s17-in-f5:https   ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.153:51976    hkg12s16-in-f10:https  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.153:51986    a-0001:https           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.153:51987    a-0001:https           ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.153:51988    125:http               SYN_SENT
```

My question is that does `jupyter-notebook` requires to keep cache after 1-time token?

Answer (score 0):

It was a Windows Firewall problems. Somehow it blocks the connection from `jupyter-notebook` to localhost

I just tweaking some rules in the firewall and get it to work